# chained parameters in SnakeMake

Tags: parameters, chaining, snakemake

This appears to work in SnakeMake to chain parameters.  Is this okay to do, or is it going to cause problems in parallel environment, and should a PersistentDict be used instead?

```
rule a:
    params:
            a = "Param A", b="Param B"
    ...


rule b:
    params: rules.a.params.b
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against that approach as it results in a [needlessly coupled system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

E.g Now "rule b" must ALWAYS be accompanied by "rule a"

I say needlessly because another option is to declare external variables in a [YAML (or JSON) file](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/advanced.html?highlight=configfile#step-2-config-files) and have both param directives accept it as an argument.

config.yaml ~ [Personal Example](https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/blob/master/buildArea/input/config.yaml)

```
a: Param A
b: Param B
```

Snakefile ~ [Personal Example with just a single rule](https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/blob/master/modules/vcfGenUtil_varScan/mpileup2vcf_single)

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule a:
    ...
    params:
        importantRuleAVar = config["a"]
    ....


rule b:
    ...
    params:
        importantRuleBVar = config["a"]
    ...
```

This is critical in my pipeline as I need the same wildcard_constraint regex for large parts of my pipeline, yet I didn't want to end up coupling all the rules together.

Also good for things like quality thresholds on aligners. Sometimes you'll use similar thresholds in different aligners for comparative purposes.